# How to check presence of the element with particular index in the list?

Tags: python

I extract the data received from 3rd party server:

```
data = json.loads(response)
if data:
    result = data.get('result')
    if result and len(result)>=38 and len(result[38])>=2: 
        for item in result[38][2]:
        ...
```

The idea of the condition is to check if the list contains element with index 38 (`result[38]`) and subelement with index 2 (`result[38][2]`), but looks like it doesn't work since I get the following exceptions -

> if result and len(result)>=38 and len(result[38])>=2:
>
> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

or

> for item in result[38][2]:
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

How should I modify my condition?

Comment: Catching `IndexError` exception could be one of the solution.

Comment: The value of `result[38]` is None.

Comment: Additionally you can check for `result[38]` for type `list`. Like `if result and len(result)>=38 and type(result[38]) == list and len(result[38])>=2:` but I would suggest you to implement with `try/catch` block capturing possible exceptions like `IndexError` and `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `result[38]` value is `None`, and `len(result[38])` fails because the `None` singleton has no length. Even if it was not `None`, your test could also fail because you need **39** elements for index 38 to exist, but you only test if there are at least 38 elements. If there are exactly 38 elements, your `len(result) >= 38` test would be true but you'd still get an `IndexError`.

Use exception handling, rather than testing every element:

```
data = json.loads(response)
try:
    for item in data['result'][38][2]:
        # ...
except (KeyError, TypeError, IndexError):
    # either no `result` key, no such index, or a value is None
    pass
```

This is far simpler than testing all the intervening elements:

```
if result and len(result) > 38 and result[38] and len(result[38]) > 2:
```

Comment: Exceptions must not be used as flow control elements. It's better to test the elements before using them.

Comment: @PacoAbato You must be new to Python: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: @PacoAbato: Python is not Java or C++. In **Python**, using exceptions for flow control is *a honking great idea*. It makes the code more readable and more robust, provided you use it to catch only specific exceptions.

Comment: @PacoAbato: exception handling in Python is cheap, often cheaper than testing every element in a nested structure like this. In other languages, exception handling is relatively expensive, and thus discouraged.

Comment: I suppose that it's a matter of style. IMHO using exceptions as flow control makes the code easier to write but more difficult to read. If the python style is to use them, ok I'll not complain again but I would write a check function and call it before using the result object.